# How to know on which column we have to apply index on table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose we have table that contains 100 columns. I want to apply index on that table, how can I determine those columns we have to apply an index?

Comment: It depends on so many factors. What types of queries are executed over your table? How often? How often data is modified? How data is modified - inserts only, or/and updates and deletes? What's the primary key definition? My advice is to give up finding easy solution. You need to read a lot to be able to get the right decision. Check this article and don't go fast - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you have a table with so many columns then you are probably doing something wrong.

But besides that look into your queries and as a rule of thumb you index the columns that you use in your `where` and `order by` clauses of the queries.

All infos the database needs to find or order a record should be indexed. Generally speaking.

For instance

```
select top 10 name, description 
from your_table
where status = 1 
order by date desc
```

For this query the 2 columns `status` and `date` should be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Index on table depends on which columns you want to put WHERE clause.

Once you are able to know columns to use for WHERE clause you can create Index over them.

Typically numeric columns are good choice for Indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This query show missing indexes that should be created using a SQL server internal statistics. Also, analyze one more time every index which you want to create. Don't create more than 5-10 indexes per table.

```
SELECT TOP 25
    dm_mid.database_id AS DatabaseID,
    dm_migs.avg_user_impact*(dm_migs.user_seeks+dm_migs.user_scans) Avg_Estimated_Impact,
    dm_migs.last_user_seek AS Last_User_Seek,
    OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) AS [TableName],
    'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) + '_'
    + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.equality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','') 
    + CASE
    WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL
    AND dm_mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN '_'
    ELSE ''
    END
    + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.inequality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','')
    + ']'
    + ' ON ' + dm_mid.statement
    + ' (' + ISNULL (dm_mid.equality_columns,'')
    + CASE WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND dm_mid.inequality_columns 
    IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE
    '' END
    + ISNULL (dm_mid.inequality_columns, '')
    + ')'
    + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + dm_mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS Create_Statement
    FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups dm_mig
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats dm_migs
    ON dm_migs.group_handle = dm_mig.index_group_handle
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details dm_mid
    ON dm_mig.index_handle = dm_mid.index_handle
    WHERE dm_mid.database_ID = DB_ID()
    ORDER BY Avg_Estimated_Impact DESC
```

Author blog: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/